# Tensorflow on Ubuntu 16.04 Not Installing

Tags: tensorflow, pip, ubuntu-16.04

I'm trying to install the GPU version of Tensorflow using Virtualenv on Ubuntu 16.04 and Python 3.6 (Anaconda), but it keeps on outputting these errors

```
tensorflow-gpu 1.7.0 requires numpy>=1.13.3, which is not installed.
tensorflow-gpu 1.7.0 requires six>=1.10.0, which is not installed.
tensorboard 1.7.0 requires numpy>=1.12.0, which is not installed.
tensorboard 1.7.0 requires six>=1.10.0, which is not installed.
tensorboard 1.7.0 requires werkzeug>=0.11.10, which is not installed.
protobuf 3.5.2.post1 requires six>=1.9, which is not installed.
html5lib 0.9999999 requires six, which is not installed.
grpcio 1.10.0 requires six>=1.5.2, which is not installed.
bleach 1.5.0 requires six, which is not installed.
absl-py 0.1.13 requires six, which is not installed.
```

I've tried installing both numpy and six using `sudo pip install numpy six` both in the virtualenv and out of it, but the error is still present. Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: Are you sure you're using the right `pip`? It might be installing them on Python 2 and not Python 3, try `pip3`.

Comment: @quartata `pip --version` outputs that it's running off of Python 3.6, but it does state that it's an older version of `pip` inside the virtualenv. When I try running `pip install --upgrade pip`, the same error as above shows up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the conda and virtualenv simultaneously which is usually a bad idea. If you installed Python from anaconda use their environment tool.

```
conda create -n tensorflow pip python=3.6

source activate tensorflow

pip install --ignore-installed --upgrade\
    https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/linux/gpu/tensorflow_gpu-1.6.0-cp36-cp36m-linux_x86_64.whl
```

Additionally, have a look at how to [install tensorflow with anaconda](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_linux#installing_with_anaconda).

Comment: I guess that's what it was. Using that method works perfectly,. Thanks!